# Pthread путает параметры в pthread_create()

Tags: c++, pthread

В цикле во время каждой итерации цикла создаю 2 thread-а при помощи `pthread_create()`. Оба треда должны получать разные данные. А на деле получают одни и те же, которые были предназначены для 2-ого треда :

```
struct So{
    int a,b;
};

void * fn1(void * some) {
    auto data = (So*) some;
    std::cout << "Thread a=" << data->a << " b=" << data->b <<std::endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
  pthread_t tid[8];
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
          So args{index*i, (index + 1)*i};
          pthread_create(&tid[index], nullptr, fn1, (void *) &args);
      }
      for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
          pthread_join(tid[index], nullptr);
      }
  }
}
```

Если что на выходе получаем что-то такое:

```
Thread a=0 b=0
Thread a=0 b=0
Thread a=1 b=2
Thread a=1 b=2
```

В моём понимании должно было быть что-то вроде:

```
Thread a=0 b=0
Thread a=0 b=0
Thread a=0 b=1  <--- Тут отличия
Thread a=1 b=2
```

Что может являться причиной такого поведения?

P.S. Ответ дан как в комментарии, так и в секции ответы. Но хочу добавить, что стоит удалять выделенный на куче объект, т.е. перед `pthread_exit(NULL)` добавить `delete data;`.

Comment: Потоки (в отличии от процессов)  используют одну и ту же память (так и было задумано проектировщиками).  Просто делайте malloc (или new) перед созданием потока, и передавайте каждому его уникальную копию аргументов

Answer (score 1):

Вы передаете в поток указатель на структуру в автоматически управляемой памяти (на стеке), которая может быть удалена сразу после создания потока, но еще до его реального запуска. Естественно, что вы наблюдаете неопределённое поведение, с тем же успехом там могли быть случайные числа.

Comment: т.е. обязательно выделять через `new`?

Comment: Дело тут не в UB (даже если бы TC использовал память, которая не освобождалась, то при таком подходе результат был бы тем же)